# Netbeans java platform shell problem with Scanner input

Tags: java, netbeans-11

I tried this in netbeans 11.2 (tools-->open java platform shell)

```
[1]-> Scanner a=new Scanner(System.in);
|  a ==> java.util.Scanner[delimiters=\p{javaWhitespace}+][position=0][match valid=fa ...
[2]-> System.out.print("give number=");
[3]-> a.nextLine();
```

i can see the output window but i can not enter values.Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: I haven't used the Netbeans in a while now but shouldn't you use the "terminal" window instead?

Comment: @Amongalen thanks for your answer.I do not think so.if you see here,it shows output window-->https://dzone.com/articles/nb-class-console-input-regular-exp

Comment: What about the `JavaApplication1(run)` tab then?

Comment: i want to use it in netbeans jshell not as java application.